# UWP NavigationView - Adding MenuItems with VisualStudio GUI

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, uwp

I am playing around with UWP and I have a small problem with the NavigationViewer. I can add some navigation items, but only with XAML or C#. How can I add items over VisualStudio GUI. I mean this button here:

[Adding MenuItems Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sGJe.png)

Do I have to enable something? That's the same button like for a TreeView. Click on it and I can add some items to the TreeView (over GUI).

Comment: Which's the property that you say you could add some items to the TreeView (over GUI)?

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT Sorry, didn't get any notifications about your comment. 
**TreeView WPF/XAML**: `Add a TreeView. Go to "Items" > in the properties, click the button [...] > Select in the DropDownMenu "Other Type" (idk if this is correct, I am using another language) > search for "TreeViewItem" > add it to the TreeView and in the properties field, write something in the "Header" > "OK" and your are good to go.`

**TreeView WindowsForms**: `Add a TreeView > click on the button from the "Nodes" property > Add something ... (similiar like above).`

Comment: What you said is the TreeView control in WPF. The UWP project doesn't support this operation.

Comment: Okay, it's not that big of a problem. Thanks for helping!